Kubernetes does not updating proper health probe rule
I am installing ingress controller with below command in AKS cluster
helm upgrade --install nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --version  4.7.1  \
    --namespace $NAMESPACE \
    --namespace $NAMESPACE \
    --create-namespace \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=$NAMESPACE \
    --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=$NAMESPACE \
    --set controller.ingressClass=$NAMESPACE \
    --set controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue="nginx.com/nginx" \
    --set controller.ingressClassResource.enabled=true \
    --set controller.ingressClassByName=true \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz \
    -f nginx.yaml

Installation was successful but I cannot reach nginx via loadbalancer IP.
After debugging we identified health probe is set as   C:/Program Files/Git/healthz instead of just /healthz in azure load balancer.
If we change maullay to /healthz it works.
Please help to fix why it is setting up C:/Program Files/Git/healthz any syntax error in helm command ?


The issue with the health probe path being set incorrectly to C:/Program Files/Git/healthz instead of /healthz is related to the environment in which the helm command is being run. When using Git Bash on Windows, it attempts to translate POSIX pathnames to Windows pathnames, which is why the path gets prefixed with C:/Program Files/Git. To fix this issue, the user needs to prevent Git Bash from attempting to convert the Unix-like path to a Windows path by using a double forward slash // at the beginning of the path in the Helm command.

The issue you're encountering with the health probe path being set incorrectly to C:/Program Files/Git/healthz instead of /healthz is related to the environment in which you are running the helm command. When you use Git Bash on Windows, it attempts to translate POSIX pathnames to Windows pathnames, which is why the path gets prefixed with C:/Program Files/Git.
To fix this issue, you need to prevent Git Bash from attempting to convert the Unix-like path to a Windows path. You can achieve this by using a double forward slash // at the beginning of the path in your Helm command, as mentioned earlier.
Here's how you can correct the health probe path

Open Git Bash on Windows.

Set the namespace for your operations (if not already set):


    export NAMESPACE=your-namespace


Run the helm command with the corrected annotation for the health probe path
helm upgrade --install nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --version 4.7.1 \
    --namespace $NAMESPACE \
    --create-namespace \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=$NAMESPACE \
    --set controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue="nginx.com/nginx" \
    --set controller.ingressClassResource.enabled=true \
    --set controller.ingressClassByName=true \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=//healthz \
    -f nginx.yaml

After running the corrected helm command, check the service to ensure the annotation has been set correctly

The output should show service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path: /healthz.
Once confirmed, attempt to reach your NGINX service via the LoadBalancer IP again. By using the double slash //healthz, Git Bash will not modify the path, and it will be correctly set in the Azure Load Balancer configuration.
References:

Install NGINX Ingress Controller
Quickstart: Deploy a Scalable & Secure WordPress instance on AKS - Install NGINX Ingress Controller

